# Optimally cooling a cup of broth

Tags: temperature, optimization

Say I have a cup of broth with volume V1 and it's too hot to drink.
I want to cool it down as quickly as possible.

- the current temp of the cup is T1
- I want to drink the cup when it cools to T2
- I have a glass of water at volume V2 that is at temperature T3, which is less than T1, and I am willing to pour the entire glass of water with the cup of soup.

**What is the optimal time to pour the glass of water into the cup of soup to cool it down?** Perhaps we can assume a continuous pour over time, or a discrete one time pour, they might be two different solutions, I am not sure.

Is there some formula/function we can use to determine the optimal time?

The question is based around how the cooling of the cup is non-linear wrt to the temperature differential between T1 and T2.

Comment: Is this already known to you, or even relevant?? http://www.ugrad.math.ubc.ca/coursedoc/math100/notes/diffeqs/cool.html

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/81910/